# How do I generate values in a column based on former values in the same column?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe

```
df=pd.Dataframe([{'RegionName':'Alabama', 'State':'Alabama'},
                {'RegionName':'Auburn', 'State':np.NaN},
                {'RegionName':'Florence', 'State':np.NaN},
                {'RegionName':'Arizona', 'State':'Arizona'},
                {'RegionName':'Flagstaff', 'State':np.NaN},
                {'RegionName':'Tempe', 'State':np.NaN}])
```

Now the 'State' column for 'Auburn' and 'Florence' should be 'Alabama', for 'Flagstaff' and 'Tempe' should be 'Arizona'. How do I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

you just want to forward fill

```
df.ffill()
```

[image]

---

***response to comment***

```
pd.concat([d.iloc[1:] for _, d in df.ffill().groupby('State')])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. And how do I drop the first value for all the repeated states? In this case, how do I drop index 0 and index 3 without using drop index?